# Card edge detection OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have followed the tutorial on OpenCV's website for Canny Edge Detector and have been getting bad results, and pretty confused on how it works. I am using it to detect edges on a business card, then crop based on the results.

I am using this code and it is giving me back an all black image with a few white pixels. The code is based off the documentation.

```
void cannyThreshold(Mat& src_gray, Mat& dst)
{
    blur(src_gray, src_gray, cv::Size(3,3));
    Canny(src_gray, src_gray, 900, 890, 3);
    dst = Scalar::all(0);
    src_gray.copyTo(dst, src_gray);
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to detect the edges of the card?

Answer (score 0):

```
void Canny( InputArray image, OutputArray edges,
                         double threshold1, double threshold2,
                         int apertureSize=3, bool L2gradient=false );
```

You need to find best values for threshold1 and threshold2 to get better results. Look [HERE](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html#code)

Answer (score -1):

Your threshold values are too high. So instead of `Canny(src_gray, src_gray, 900, 890, 3);` try to use the following

```
Canny(src_gray, src_gray, 20, 60, 3);
```

Try with different combination of thresholds also.

Comment: why do the values have to be lower? What is the meaning of the thresholds?